# How do i receive JSON payloads from the slack API to retrieve messages using python?

Tags: python, python-requests, slack, slack-api

I have been trying to make a slack bot for quite some time but there seems to be very little documentation on the slack URL, the most in-depth instructions I have found is to use *ngrok* and then you should receive **JSON** payloads from the slack API but as I am a beginner programmer I don't have much knowledge on this. I used an *ngrok* https URL and appended /slack/actions as documented from slack and just tried a little piece of code to see if the URL was ok to receive payloads from

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://f39b39ebcdbf.ngrok.io/slack/actions')

print(r)
```

and I got a 405 error

So I am not sure what code I need to receive these payloads 
as you can probably tell I am very new at this 
so any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Can you check *https://f39b39ebcdbf.ngrok.io/slack/actions*, this URL doesn't allow get method therefore response status is coming as 405.

Comment: it came back with this error : requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'f39b39ebcdbf.ngrok.io/slack/actions': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://f39b39ebcdbf.ngrok.io/slack/actions?

Comment: i then tried the url it gave me: (Perhaps you meant f39b39ebcdbf.ngrok.io/slack/actions?) and it came back with another 405 error

Comment: Is there any username or password to be used

Answer (score 0):

Use POST Method Instead of GET.
USE URL LIKE : https://xxxxxx.ngrok.io/api/YourSlackReceviver/Action